# Catching FileNotFoundException. Problems with initializing Scanner prior to try/catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm currently working on some exception handling and have run into an issue when using a driver class. The driver errors: "Unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown." I'm unable to edit the driver to add "throws FileNotFoundException" to main.

Here is a code snippet from the main program. I know I need to catch the exception with a try/catch but I can't figure out how to initialize the Scanner prior to the try block.

```
public program(String file1, String file2) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File f1 = new File(file1);
    File f2 = new File(file2);

    try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(f1); Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(f2);) 
    {
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){}

    int a = scan.nextInt(); //THIS IS WHERE I RUN INTO PROBLEMS (scan not found)
    scan.nextLine();
    int b = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing "throws FileNotFoundException"

```
public program(String file1, String file2)
{
    try
    {
        File f1 = new File(file1);
        File f2 = new File(file2);
        int a = scan.nextInt(); //THIS IS WHERE I RUN INTO PROBLEMS (scan not found)
        scan.nextLine();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
}
```